# RegExp not matching expected pattern in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I am writing a script that will take in all my Lambda functions and create a Node server for local testing. I'm trying to string out all of the dbconfig objects from each file. I use https://regexr.com/ to test out my patterns, and I have done a number of variations that all work in there, but they will not work in my script. I am at a loss as to why. The objects all look like this:

```
const dbconfig = {
  server: process.env.SERVER,
  userName: process.env.USER_NAME,
  password: process.env.PASSWORD,
  options: {
    database: process.env.DATABASE,
    table: process.env.TABLE,
    encrypt: true,
    requestTimeout: 300000,
    rowCollectionOnRequestCompletion: true,
  }
}
```

I have tried (amongst others):

- /(.+[\n\r]).+process.env(.+[\n\r])+/g
- /const dbconfig(.+[\s\n\r])+/g
- /(.+\s).+process.env(.+\s)+/g

Each one of these matches the whole object declaration as expected, but in Node it will replace:

- nothing, leaves it as is
- the first line (const dbconfig = {
- all of the lines that contain process.env but leave the rest

I have no idea why I would get the different results, and why it would fail. Any suggestions welcome!

**Edit:**
Sorry, not enough detail included. By replace I mean I am doing a substitution for an empty string ''.
I am reading in the files to an array inside a loop of directory names like this:

```
files.push(fs.readFileSync(`../lambda/${folder}/index.js`, {encoding: 'utf8'}));
```

I am pulling out the required libraries from each of these like this:

```
let imports = new Set();
let arr;
files.forEach((file, idx) => {
  while ((arr = replaceOptions.from[0].exec(file)) !== null) {
    imports.add(arr[0]);
  }
});
```

I then join the files into a master single file, strip out the requires and trying to do these configs, and will append a single copy at the top:

```
fs.writeFileSync('joined.js', files.join('\n'));

try {
  const results = replace.sync(replaceOptions);
  console.log('Replacement results:', results);
}
catch (error) {
  console.error('Error occurred:', error);
}

fs.writeFileSync('server.js', Array.from(imports.values()).join('\n'));
fs.appendFileSync('server.js', fs.readFileSync('joined.js'));
```

I was formerly doing the string replace myself, but then ended up using npm package replace-in-file jsut for ease / in case I was stuffing up something there.
And yes, I do realise this code is a bit messy and inefficient currently, it's just been iterations of trying to get a base achievement of the desired outcome.

Comment: can you try: `/\s*const\sdbconfig(.+\s).+process\.env(.+\s)+}\s*/gm`
demo: https://regex101.com/r/k1xG06/1/

Comment: @Allan that one also just leave the whole thing there

Comment: What do you mean by _'replacing'_ ? I don't see any replacing. I don't see any regex usage, where is all that stuff ?

Comment: Hi @sln, I've added some extra info in

Comment: Does it mean you need to just pass an empty string to some method if the text contains `process.env.`? `if (~text.indexOf('process.env.')) { return ''; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know why I would get the difference between an online regex builder/tester and Node, but there you go. I do now have a working implementation:

```
/(.*\s*).+process\.env(.*\s*)*?\}\s*\}/gm
```

Comment: `(.*\s*).+` and `(.*\s*)*?` will not work well with long texts.